# How do you turn off the cave ambience?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On beta testing version for **1.16.0.57+**, Minecraft has introduced the cave ambience which I'm afraid of.

I been wondering if there is a switch in the settings or something that will remove the cave ambience from Minecraft Bedrock Edition.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to create a custom resource pack that plays sound files that are just silence for the cave sounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the volume for all the ambience sounds under Options > General > Audio > [Ambient/Environment](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Options#Audio).  However, it will also affect the sound of fireworks and entering/exiting water.

There is [a suggestion](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/360043711352-Remove-Cave-Noise-Sounds) to remove the cave ambience sounds in the Minecraft feedback page, but so far it hasn't been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is, but if there was it would be under settings>muisic.
another way would just be to turn off your sound entirely, but maybe you don't want to do that.